# Returning links inside iframe using a function in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, iframe, asynchronous, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to get the links from inside an iframe and return them as a function result, my simplified code looks something like this:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
        webSecurityEnabled: false
});

var url = casper.cli.get(0);

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo(msg);
})

casper.start(url, function () {
    thelinks = getLinksFromIframes( casper );
    console.log("doesn't work:" + thelinks);
});

function getLinksFromIframes( context ) {
        var links = [];

        var iframes = context.evaluate( function() {
                var iframes = [];
                [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"), function(iframe, i) { iframes.push( i ); });
                return iframes;
        });

        iframes.forEach( function( index ) {
            context.withFrame(index, function() {
                links = links.concat( this.getElementsAttribute( 'a', 'href' ) );
                console.log("works: " + links);
            });
        });

        return links;
}

casper.run(function() {
    console.log('done');
    this.exit();
});
```

The problem is that the function doesn't return anything, I can only read the links var inside `withFrame`, i know there are other ways to get the links, but the code is this way because it part of something more complex that will analyze nested iframes, and the amount of iframes inside iframes is unknown. Is there any way I could wait on `withFrame` or something that will allow me to return the links as the function result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected, because `casper.withFrame` is an asynchronous step function. Like all other functions that begin with either `then` or `wait`, it schedules a step in the CasperJS execution queue.

When those scheduled steps are executed (at the end of the current step, which is the `then` callback of `casper.start` in your case), `getLinksFromIframes` has long finished and returned an empty array.

> Is there any way I could wait on withIframe or something that will allow me to return the links as the function result?

No, but you can use a callback:

```
function getLinksFromIframes( callback ) {
    var links = [];

    var iframes = this.evaluate( function() {
        var iframes = [];
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"), function(iframe, i) { iframes.push( i ); });
        return iframes;
    });

    iframes.forEach( function( index ) {
        this.withFrame(index, function() {
            links = links.concat( this.getElementsAttribute( 'a', 'href' ) );
            console.log("works: " + links);
        });
    }, this);

    this.then(function(){
        callback.call(this, links);
    });
}

casper.start(url, function () {
    getLinksFromIframes.call(this, function(links){
        thelinks = links;
        console.log("Links: " + thelinks);
    });
})
.then(function(){
    console.log("Links later: " + thelinks);
})
.run();
```

Comment: reading your code it make sense, but I am not getting no console.log output, this is the full code im testing http://pastebin.com/AN3fxvS1 the output looks like this http://pastebin.com/y7AZ5QLV I am testing on localhost with a simple html that includes another html file with iframe, that second file contains a few <a> tags.

Comment: Sorry, the `this` in `this.withFrame` was not bound to `casper`. I fixed it.

Comment: Yea thanks, i got it working looking at the first code you posted before editing, adding the original context param now everything works, im able to navigate nested iframes until the required level and grab all the links, thank you very much.