# Returning links inside multiple-levels iframe using a function in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, casperjs

I am trying to get all links under multiple level iframes in CasperJS. There was a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672411/returning-links-inside-iframe-using-a-function-in-casperjs) to resolve the case that there is one-level iframe. I am trying to put getLinksFromIFrame inside the getLinksFromIfram to do recurive traverse but failed.

For this code, how should I do it for multiple-level iframes?

```
function getLinksFromIframes( callback ) {
    var links = [];

    var iframes = this.evaluate( function() {
        var iframes = [];
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"), function(iframe, i) { iframes.push( i ); });
        return iframes;
    });

    iframes.forEach( function( index ) {
        this.withFrame(index, function() {
            links = links.concat( this.getElementsAttribute( 'a', 'href' ) );
            console.log("works: " + links);
        });
    }, this);

    this.then(function(){
        callback.call(this, links);
    });
}

casper.start(url, function () {
    getLinksFromIframes.call(this, function(links){
        thelinks = links;
        console.log("Links: " + thelinks);
    });
})
.then(function(){
    console.log("Links later: " + thelinks);
})
.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
        //    verbose: true,
        //    logLevel: "debug",
        webSecurityEnabled : false
    });
//page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {console.log(msg);};
casper.on('remote.message', function (message) {
    this.echo(message);
});

casper.start("http://domu-test-2/node/1", function () {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        var i,
        x = document.querySelector("iframe#test") //First iframe
            .contentDocument.querySelector("iframe#test2") //Second iframe in the first
            .contentDocument.querySelectorAll("a"); //Links
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            console.log(x[i].href)
        }
    })
}).wait(1000).run();
```

**It was hard, but i've created this script:**

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
        //  verbose: true,
        //    logLevel: "debug",
        webSecurityEnabled : false
    });
var links = [];
function get_links(obj) {
    return obj.evaluate(function () {
        var i,
            l = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
            l2 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            l2[i] = l[i].href;
        }
        return l2
    });
}
function unique(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (/http(.*)?/.test(arr[i])) {
            var str = arr[i];
            obj[str] = true;
        }
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}

function getLinksFromIframes(callback) {
    this.echo("Here we come: " + this.getCurrentUrl() + "\n");
    function to_frame(obj) {
        var iframes = to_evaluate(obj);
        iframes.forEach(function (index) {
            this.withFrame(index, function () {
                this.echo("We are here: " + this.getCurrentUrl());
                var l = unique(get_links(this));
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                    console.log(l[i]);
                    links.push(l[i])
                }
                links = unique(links);
                console.log("");
                to_frame(this) //multi lvl
            }); //The first iframe
        }, obj);
    }
    function to_evaluate(obj) {
        return obj.evaluate(function () {
            var iframes = [];
            [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"), function (iframe, i) {
                iframes.push(i);
            });
            return iframes;
        })
    }
    to_frame(this);
    this.then(function () {
        callback.call(this);
    });
}

casper.start("http://domu-test-2/node/1", function () {
    getLinksFromIframes.call(this, function () {
        console.log("Done!\n");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            console.log(links[i]);
        }
    });
}).then(function () {}).run();
```

Note:
Now we have a full multi lvl.

```
./casperjs test.js >>/dev/stdout
Here we come: http://domu-test-2/node/1

We are here: http://domu-test-2/node/2
http://link_1_inside_iframe(1.1)_from_main_frame

We are here: http://domu-test-2/node/3
http://link_1_inside_iframe(2.1)_from_1.1

We are here: http://domu-test-2/node/5
http://link_1_inside_iframe(2.2)_from_1.1

We are here: http://domu-test-2/node/4
http://link_1_inside_iframe(1.2)_from_main_frame

We are here: http://domu-test-2/node/6
http://link_1_inside_iframe(2.1)_from_1.2
```

Comment: It seems, we now have a full recursion.
i've created node1 with 2 iframes: the first has a link, and 2 iframes with a link in each, the second has a link, and 1 iframe with a link inside. All seems to be good.

Comment: I hope this script will always work as expected, but maybe it needs some improvement. I wonder, if  **Artjom B.** leaves us?

Comment: If I want add timeout to wait for all iframes load finished, adding the wait(seconds) is not helpful, right?

Comment: I think yes. You can mark this post as a solution, let the people know it works. It was really interesting to work on it, so thank you for this question!

Comment: If I want the links grouped by first-level iframe, how should I refactor the to_frame function? My thought is basically the links would be list of list, within withFrame a new list will be created and then passing it to the child iframe. So how should I "backtrace" the links? Thanks ahead

Comment: Honestly, i don't know how to do that. I think you need to open new question about that.

Comment: @Igor I haven't left. :) Your code is rather hard to read with all the missing indentation. Maybe, you can remove the first snippet, indent the code in the second snippet and describe in text what the challenge is in this specific case. That way future readers will have a better chance to learn something instead of just copy-pasting the code. (And increases the chance of getting upvotes)

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm glad to see you here! I don't exactly know, how to improve the answer, you can help me, by changing it.