# How to: Print Select Option Values?

Tags: javascript, list, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to print the values of each option in the "complist", which looks something like this:

```
<select name="complist">
    <option selected="" value="111 1">107-83-5&nbsp;&nbsp;C6H14&nbsp;&nbsp;2-Methylpentane</option>
    <option value="1 24">&nbsp;75-07-0&nbsp;&nbsp;C2H4O&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Acetaldehyde</option>
    <option value="6 2">106-93-4&nbsp;&nbsp;C2H4Br2&nbsp;&nbsp;Ethylene bromide</option>
</select>
```

I tried:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        //var options = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="complist"]'); 
        var options = document.querySelector('select[name="complist"]');
    })
    for (var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
        console.log(">>> " + options[i].textContent);
    }
});
```

But I get the following error:

- Error>    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: options, ERROR
- File>    phantomjs://code/gruppen3.js, WARNING
- Line>    113, WARNING
- Function>, WARNING

Which results from *options.length* in the for-loop:/

I tried a couple of other ways (e.g. [How to select an option with CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136361/how-to-select-an-option-with-casperjs)) to return the list of options, but nothing has worked so far.

To see exactly what I am talking about you can:

1. Navigate to http://www.ddbst.com/unifacga.html
2. Select option no. 4 (DDB search)
3. Enter e.g. 174 as the ddb number and submit.
4. You should now see a "complist" with a single option for water.

How can I return the option value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`casper.evaluate` executes javascript inside of a sandbox. You have to specifically return data from that function because variables created there will not exist in the main script. The correct implemenation:

```
/// MAIN SCRIPT CONTEXT
casper.then(function(){

    // Value which is returned from sandbox must be saved in some local variable
    var localOptions = this.evaluate(function(){
        // SANDBOX CONTEXT -------------------------------

        // Dont return objects. Return arrays, strings, numbers
        var options = [];
        options = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[name="complist"] option'), function(option){
            return option.innerText;
        });
        // You have to return scraped data back to the outer script
        return options;

        // END OF SANDBOX CONTEXT -----------------------

    });

    console.log(">>> " + localOptions);
    // just "options" array does not exist here    
});
```

Comment: First of it works; thank you :) And I think I mostly understand everything; however, I will write out the steps in my own words if anyone has pointers:
1. "then" creates a step within the casperJS framework.
2. "evaluate" opens up the DOM (from phantomJS?) in a sandbox.
3. Instead of for-looping the option objects, the "map" class (I assume because of the dot) is used to load "option" values into an array called "options".

Comment: Here ", function(option)" is used in the call, but we could have used ", function(img)" if the selector was for images?? In short, I think I understand the semantics but how can I learn the correct syntax required to use this answer in other (similar) problems?
4. The options list is then returned back to the outer script ("then" step), which is printed to the console...

Answer (score 2):

**I've tested it, and it works!**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true,logLevel: "debug"});
casper.start('http://www.ddbst.com/unifacga.html',function(){
this.withFrame('ircframe',function(){
this.click('input[id="ID4"]');

this.wait(0,function(){
this.fillSelectors('form[name="opeform"]', {'input[name="ddbnumber"]': '155'},false);
});
this.wait(0,function(){this.click('input[name="search_ddbnum"]');});
this.wait(0,function(){
var i,o=this.fetchText('select[name="complist"]');
console.log("The value is: "+o)
});
});
});
casper.then(function(){this.capture('test.png');});
casper.run();
```

You can run it with:
`./casperjs --web-security=no test.js  >>/dev/stdout`

Comment: Updated: `now faster x2!`

Comment: Take a look at [my latest work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558731/returning-links-inside-multiple-levels-iframe-using-a-function-in-casperjs/40568059#40568059) - that was extremely interesting, but hard!

Comment: I recommend you to mark this answer as a solution, to let the people know it really works. I was glad to deal with it, iframes are really interesting thing!

Comment: thanks again! You definitely gave me some food for thought e.g. it is much (MUCH) more compact than I have at the moment. However, as a new-bee, the map procedure seems more intuitive to me (this is my first casperJS project, or JS for that matter). Unfortunately, I cannot mark two solutions to the question...

Comment: @Igor, to make your answers better, don't just give the code, try to show what was wrong and tell how you made it right. Also, a well-indented example is easier to understand.

Comment: @Vaviloff, i think you are right, but i'm just a beginner here in any way. To me, the main thing is that it works, and not worthless at all.